# Trace info of referenced assembly doesn't show up on Trace tab of Glimpse, except on first request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, glimpse

I've been pulling my hair out today trying to find out why trace info isn't showing up in the relevant Glimpse tab. I have a site, running on my own PC, running ASP.NET MVC5 and Glimpse 1.8.6. Glimpse otherwise works fine, and the security policy is set to allow specific user roles and remote access, which is working.

My web application references an assembly containing an EF Code First database, and for background (in case it's relevant) I'm overriding the SaveChanges() method to automatically audit changes, and one part of that isn't working as expected, so I'm trying to use a bunch of Trace.WriteLine() statements to track down the problem.

The problem I seem to be having is that only two lines of trace info show up in my Glimpse tab, from a method called early on in the page request cycle (it's in the constructor for the EF DBContext). After that, no trace info is logged. If I throw an exception where the Trace.WriteLine() or Trace.TraceInformation() line is, the app crashes with that exception, so I know that code is indeed getting called. And calling SaveChanges() does save changes, so the code where the Trace statements are is actually running.

I've also noticed that after making web.config changes and re-publishing the site, on the first request I see tons of Trace info, as expected - but every subsequent request only shows those first two lines.

It seems this is specifically an issue with the referenced assembly. I added some trace lines elsewhere in the web application, and they seem to always show as expected. But the trace lines in the referenced assembly only show up on the first request after publishing the site, and never again.

The referenced assembly is being compiled with DEBUG and TRACE constant, and with full debug info.

I have Googled the crap out of this, to the point where I got a message that Google thought I was a robot and presented me with a CAPTCHA to continue, which I've never seen or was even aware they had! From what I can tell, this should work, to the point I've seen questions from people asking how to turn OFF the tracing info, so there must be something simple I've missed that's going to make me facepalm and hang my head in shame, but if historic precedent holds, I won't figure it out myself until just after asking for help, so here's hoping!

Thus, my questions are:

1. Is the Trace info from referenced assemblies expected to show up in Glimpse, or am I misunderstanding how that can be used? Maybe there's some default filter I'm missing that limits the trace scope?
2. What configuration settings are needed to enable this? I followed various combinations of web.config settings from the Glimpse site (but for Trace, not for TraceSource), to no avail. And as mentioned, it seems that Glimpse is showing some trace info, just not as much as I expect.

Any suggestions are greatly welcomed! Even snarky responses from people who like to make others look dumb are welcome, if it indeed gets me where I need to be. :)

Comment: Adam, it sounds like this should be working. Can you get the trace statements to show up anywhere? (Output panel for example)

Comment: I have seen these trace statements in the Immediate window in VS while debugging locally, just not in Glimpse. It's what made me think I might have been misunderstanding how it was expected to work in Glimpse.